View not updating unless a delay is added
I have a view onto which I want to display an alert dialog if there is an error. I have created a custom view for this as follows:
struct CustomAlertView: View {
    let title: String
    let message: String?
    let primaryActionTitle: String
    let primaryAction: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title3.bold())
                .padding(Constants.titlePadding)
            
            Text(message ?? "")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(3, reservesSpace: true)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            Button(action: primaryAction) {
                Text(primaryActionTitle)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, Constants.buttonHorizontalPadding)
            .padding(.vertical, Constants.buttonVerticalPadding)
            .background(.accent)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.buttonCornerRadius))
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Constants.alertBackground)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.alertCornerRadius))
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.borderCornerRadius)
                .stroke(
                    Constants.borderColor
                        .opacity(Constants.borderOpacity),
                    lineWidth: Constants.borderWidth
                )
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

This gets called in the view like so:
struct ProductListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProductListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                content

                if viewModel.showAlert {
                    CustomAlertView(
                        title: "Something went wrong",
                        message: viewModel.error?.localizedDescription,
                        primaryActionTitle: "Try again",
                        primaryAction: {
                            viewModel.dismissAlertAndRefresh()
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .refreshable {
                viewModel.refreshList()
            }
        }
    }
}

And my view model looks like this:
@MainActor
final class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    /// Holds any errors that may be thrown.
    @Published var error: Error?
    /// Property to decide whether an alert should be shown to the user.
    @Published var showAlert = false
    /// Collection to hold Product object.
    @Published var products: [Product] = []

    * * *        

    /// APIservice used for fetching product data.
    private let apiService: APIService
    
    /// Initialises the APIService and loads the initial data.
    init(apiService: APIService = APIService()) {
        self.apiService = apiService
        loadData()
    }
    
    /// Starts an asynchronous task to fetch products from the API.
    func loadData() {
        Task {
            do {
                try await fetchProducts()
            } catch {
                self.error = error
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
    }
        
    /// Fetches products from the APIservice and updates the products array.
    func fetchProducts() async throws {
        self.products = try await apiService.fetchProducts()
    }
    
    func dismissAlertAndRefresh() {
        self.showAlert = false
        self.error = nil
        self.refreshList()
    }

    /// Clears the product list, resets sorting, clears errors, and reloads data.
    func refreshList() {
        self.selectedSortOption = nil
        self.products.removeAll()
        isSortingMenuHidden()
        loadData()
    }
}

The problem I am having is the view is not updating quick enough before the loadData() method is called. The UI will just show a persistent dialog that can't be dismissed but I can tell from breakpoints/logs, everything is being triggered as expected. I can add an artificial delay such as the following:
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.refreshList()
}

Whilst this does resolve the issue, I suspect it's not best practice and hence I want to avoid doing such an action. I'm wondering where I am going wrong with setting the state value and how I can resolve this? Thanks!
EDIT: A native alert works fine: (But I am looking for a custom implementation)
.alert("Something went wrong", isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert, presenting: viewModel.error) { error in
    Button("Try again") {
        viewModel.dismissAlertAndRefresh()
    }
} message: { error in
     Text(error.localizedDescription)
}


Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce your issue.

I could not replicate your issue in my tests.
I present the CustomAlertView, click on the Try Again button,
the CustomAlertView is completely dismmised, then the view takes (in my test 2 seconds) to update. Is this what you get, or did I not understand your question.

You understood correctly, but it's not what I get. The view is not dismissed in the UI- my suspicion is that it is dismissed but the loadData() call is so quick that, that it reappears, on screen the view persists. I don't want an artificial delay that does fix the issue

presented my test code, that seems to work for me.

As I understand your code, your CustomAlertView will be drawn depending on the boolean property showAlert . No matter how fast the property changes, eventually, the last actual state will be drawn. So, I guess when there is such an issue, it might be in code you have not shown.
As a side note, you are not showing a "dialog", it's just a view on top of the content. Thus, you are also not "dismissing" the alert view, it's "not rendering it". A dialog is a modal view. SwiftUI has tools to represent alert views as dialog. Have a look ;)

Here is my test code where I present the CustomAlertView (using a Button),
click on the Try Again button, the CustomAlertView completely disappears,
and the view updates immediately (no delay).
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProductListView()
    }
}

struct CustomAlertView: View {
    let title: String
    let message: String?
    let primaryActionTitle: String
    let primaryAction: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title3.bold())
                .padding(22)
            
            Text(message ?? "")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .lineLimit(3, reservesSpace: true)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            Button(action: primaryAction) {
                Text(primaryActionTitle)
                    .font(.title3)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 22)
            .padding(.vertical, 22)
            .background(Color.green)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
                .stroke(Color.pink.opacity(0.5),lineWidth: 4)
        )
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ProductListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ProductListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                
                // <--- for testing
                VStack {
                    Button("Show alert") {
                        viewModel.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                    List(viewModel.products) { product in
                        Text(product.name)
                    }
                }
                
                if viewModel.showAlert {
                    CustomAlertView(
                        title: "Something went wrong",
                        message: viewModel.error?.localizedDescription,
                        primaryActionTitle: "Try again",
                        primaryAction: {
                            viewModel.dismissAlertAndRefresh()
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .refreshable {
                viewModel.refreshList()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Product: Identifiable { // <--- for testing
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct APIService: Identifiable { // <--- for testing
    let id = UUID()
    var name = "APIService"
}

@MainActor
final class ProductListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    /// Holds any errors that may be thrown.
    @Published var error: Error?
    /// Property to decide whether an alert should be shown to the user.
    @Published var showAlert = false
    /// Collection to hold Product object.
    @Published var products: [Product] = []

    /// APIservice used for fetching product data.
    private let apiService: APIService
    
    /// Initialises the APIService and loads the initial data.
    init(apiService: APIService = APIService()) {
        self.apiService = apiService
        loadData()
    }
    
    /// Starts an asynchronous task to fetch products from the API.
    func loadData() {
        Task {
            do {
                try await fetchProducts()
            } catch {
                self.error = error
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Fetches products from the APIservice and updates the products array.
    func fetchProducts() async throws {
        //  self.products = try await apiService.fetchProducts()
        
        // <--- for testing, update immediately
        self.products = [Product(name: UUID().uuidString),Product(name: UUID().uuidString),Product(name: UUID().uuidString)]
    }
    
    func dismissAlertAndRefresh() {
        self.showAlert = false
        self.error = nil
        self.refreshList()
    }
    
    /// Clears the product list, resets sorting, clears errors, and reloads data.
    func refreshList() {
     //   self.selectedSortOption = nil
        self.products.removeAll()
    //    isSortingMenuHidden()
        loadData()
    }
}

